# Knitr: adding a PDF as a vignette

Tags: r, pdf, knitr, vignette

My package has a PDF file which I'd like to include as a vignette. There are guides on the internet for doing that with [Sweave](http://www.markvanderloo.eu/yaRb/2019/01/11/add-a-static-pdf-vignette-to-an-r-package/) and [R.rsp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.rsp/vignettes/R_packages-Static_PDF_and_HTML_vignettes.pdf), but I'd like to use **knitr as the vignette engine** because we are writing another vignette in Rmd.

My latest attempt has `file.pdf` and `file.pdf.asis` inside the `vignettes/` folder, with the latter containing these two lines:

```
%\VignetteIndexEntry{title}
%\VignetteEngine{knitr::asis_output}
```

FWIW, if I use R.rsp as an engine, the second line above can simply contain `%\VignetteEngine{R.rsp::asis}` and that vignette builds fine, so one suspicion I have is that I am simply using the wrong knitr equivalent.

I've also tried some monstrosities involving a mix of a YAML header and LaTeX inclusion of the PDF, which didn't work either:

```
---
title: "title"
author: "yes"
output: pdf_document
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{title}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---

\includepdf{file.pdf}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the power of open-source software, I was able to run `browseVignettes()`, go through my installed packages containing a mix of HTML and PDF vignettes, and eventually check out the source code for the [jsonlite](https://cran.r-project.org/package=jsonlite) package. This led me to a simple solution I thought about but immediately dismissed because I *thought* it wasn't possible: **declare *both* `knitr` and `R.rsp` as vignette engines.**

So my package's `DESCRIPTION` now includes:

```
VignetteBuilder: R.rsp, knitr
```

and I have an Rmd vignette containing `%\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}` on its YAML header and a `file.pdf.asis` containing `%\VignetteEngine{R.rsp::asis}`.